# Refile and keep the original

Tags: commands

How to refile while keeping a copy of the original object in org-mode? In other words refiling works as a cut&paste while I would like to have a copy&paste.

Comment: It would be interesting to "link" the two objects such that if one of the two is marked as DONE the other is updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No big problem, it's documented in the info page ["(org) Refile and copy"](http://orgmode.org/manual/Refile-and-copy.html)

`C-c` `M-w`     (org-copy)

Copying works like refiling, except that the original note is not deleted.